# Symfony2 - How to set, and get, options when using a Form Class?

Tags: php, symfony

I am using Form Classes to build the various form in my project.

In the Entity Type file, for the buildForm function, there is a secondary parameter of "array $options" (this is shown in the official Symfony 2 Documentation, but never mentioned, ever!)

I have fed an array into the createForm function in my controller but now I am totally stumped on how to retrieve the stored values?

```
$form = $this->createForm(new ProductType(array(), array('id' => '2')), $product);
```

The only thing I have found about getting the options is using the getOption() function, but that doesn't exist in Symfony 2 (the post I found was from 2010).

I tried using:

```
$id = $options['id'];
```

But when I try to use $id anywhere, I get the error:

> Notice: Undefined index: id

What gives?

How do I retrieve my values from the $options array? Am I even setting them correctly in the first place?

EDIT - More code:

Form Class

```
<?php

namespace DEMO\DemoBundle\Form\Product;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilder;

class ProductType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name')
            ->add('slug')
            ->add('reference')
            ->add('description')
            ->add('active_from')
            ->add('active_till')
            ->add('is_active')
            ->add('category', 'entity', array(
                'class' => 'DEMO\DemoBundle\Entity\Product\ProductCategory',
                'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) {
                    return $er->createQueryBuilder('u')
                        ->where('u.section = :id')
                        ->setParameter('id', ***ID VARIABLE NEEDS TO GO HERE***)
                        ->orderBy('u.root', 'ASC')
                        ->addOrderBy('u.lft', 'ASC');
                },
                'empty_value' => 'Choose an option',
                'property' => 'indentedName',
            ));
    }

    public function getDefaultOptions()
    {
        return array(
            'data_class' => 'DEMO\DemoBundle\Entity\Product\Product'
        );
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'demo_demobundle_product_type';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it turns out, Gregoires answer was very close, but gave me and "Undefined variable" error when trying to actually but the variable into the createQueryBuilder function.

I spent a while trying to figure out why and found the issue. You have to add an extra parameter to the function in the "query_builder" option, like such:

```
'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) use ($options) {
                    return $er->createQueryBuilder('u')
                        ->where('u.section = :id')
                        ->setParameter('id', $options['id'])
                        ->orderBy('u.root', 'ASC')
                        ->addOrderBy('u.lft', 'ASC');
                },
```

The magic setting being "use ($options)". This allows you to successfully use $options['id'] in the Query Builder.

Comment: Sorry, it is actually implemented with greg0ires answer, I copied the code incorrectly. Edited it to clear it up

Answer (score 17):

I think you're not setting them properly in the first place. You're supposed to give them as third argument to `createForm()`

EDIT: Here is how your form class could look:

```
<?php
namespace DEMO\DemoBundle\Form\Product;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilder;

class ProductType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name')
            ->add('slug')
            ->add('reference')
            ->add('description')
            ->add('active_from')
            ->add('active_till')
            ->add('is_active')
            ->add('category', 'entity', array(
                'class' => 'DEMO\DemoBundle\Entity\Product\ProductCategory',
                'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) use($options) {
                    return $er->createQueryBuilder('u')
                        ->where('u.section = :id')
                        ->setParameter('id', $options['id'])
                        ->orderBy('u.root', 'ASC')
                        ->addOrderBy('u.lft', 'ASC');
                },
                'empty_value' => 'Choose an option',
                'property' => 'indentedName',
            ));
    }

    public function getDefaultOptions()
    {
        return array(
            'data_class' => 'DEMO\DemoBundle\Entity\Product\Product',
            'id'         => null
        );
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'demo_demobundle_product_type';
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe the 3rd option for createForm() is to set options such as the following: "attr", "by_reference", "cascade_validation", "csrf_field_name", "csrf_protection", "csrf_provider", "data", "data_class", "disabled", "empty_data", "error_bubbling", "error_delay", "error_mapping", "error_type", "field_error_type", "help_block", "help_inline" etc etc (basically, I tried, and it says   "The option "id" does not exist.")

Comment: You can adapt the getDefaultOptions() method of your form class to tell your form about this option and avoid this message.

Comment: Tbh, I dont really want to go about "hacking" any of the core structure. The function buildForm() clearly has a secondary parameter to set an array of options. I want to know how it is utilised properly.

Comment: This is not hacking the core structure, this is the way to go, the getDefaultOptions() is a method that is in YOUR form class (it is if you generated your form with the cli task). It is there so that you can modify it. If you don't believe me, believe the documentation : http://symfony.com/doc/master/book/forms.html, which shows examples of modifications to this method.

Comment: That page does not show how to customise getDefaultOptions(). It only shows how to use some of the available options for that method, such as CSRF Protection and setting a data_class. Please outline exactly where it shows how to customise the method which would allow me to add in my own parameters?

Comment: I did not say it was shown in this page. But if you gave your form class in your question, I would have a good starting point to show you how to achieve this. You can have a look to vendor/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/FormFactory.php to understand how it works.

Comment: Just tried this code, and I get the following error - "Notice: Undefined variable: options in /Sites/src/DEMO/DemoBundle/Form/Product/ProductType.php line 26"

Comment: How is this even possible? $options is an argument of the method. Triple check the code, you must have made a typo.

Comment: Don't ask me, I simply implemented your code and it doesn't work.

Comment: I ask you because you can debug it and test it (and understand it, I hope). Don't you agree with me that "undefined variable" is very unlikely for this piece of code?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10709/discussion-between-greg0ire-and-mr-pablo)

Comment: Oooh I did not see you were using a closure. Editing my answer

Comment: Apparently it's not with `getDefaultOptions()` anymore, but with `setDefaultOptions()`.

Otherwise it says 

`The option "no_animal_type" does not exist. Known options are:  "action", "attr", "auto_initialize", ...`

Answer (score 9):

Let me show you what worked for me

In the Controller:

```
$form = $this->createForm(new UsersType(), $entity, array(
    'attr' => array('locationId' => $currentLocationId)));
```

In the FormType:

```
->add('location', 'entity', array(
        'class' => 'Ro\RoinventBundle\Entity\Locations',
         'query_builder' => function (\Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository $er) use ($options)
        {
            if (isset($options['attr']['locationId']) && ($options['attr']['locationId'] != NULL))
            {
                return $er->createQueryBuilder('Locations')
                    ->where('Locations.id = :param')
                    ->setParameter('param', $options['attr']['locationId']);
            }
            //else do what you want
},
));
```

Answer (score 8):

Apparently it's not with `getDefaultOptions()` anymore, but with `setDefaultOptions()`.

Otherwise it says

> The option "my_custom_option" does not exist. Known options are:  "action", "attr", "auto_initialize", ...

So, for me I had to update setDefaultOptions like this :

```
public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array('my_custom_option' => false));
    // Others if needed, like in the documentation for : 'data_class' => 'VENDOR\Bundle\Entity\MyEntity', 'csrf_protection' => true
}
```

And then you can retrieve it in the `buildForm` method

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $myCustomOption = $options['my_custom_option'];
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Well acording to this [Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/symfony2/z4RvxhuktyE)

"greg0ire" was right, in fact I have tried it and works perfect!!!. You said "I dont really want to go about "hacking" any of the core structure" but you end up using no the best approach.. in matter of fact, from my point of view, you end up doing what you didn't want to do.

So at the end you should do this:

at the formType

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('name')
        ->add('slug')
        ->add('reference')
        ->add('description')
        ->add('active_from')
        ->add('active_till')
        ->add('is_active')
        ->add('category', 'entity', array(
            'class' => 'DEMO\DemoBundle\Entity\Product\ProductCategory',
            'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) {
                return $er->createQueryBuilder('u')
                    ->where('u.section = :id')
                    ->setParameter('id', $options['id'])
                    ->orderBy('u.root', 'ASC')
                    ->addOrderBy('u.lft', 'ASC');
            },
            'empty_value' => 'Choose an option',
            'property' => 'indentedName',
        ));
}

public function getDefaultOptions()
{
    return array(
        'data_class' => 'DEMO\DemoBundle\Entity\Product\Product'
        'id' => null
    );
}
```

And in the controller

```
$form = $this->createForm(new ProductType(), $product, array('id' => $id ));
```

Answer (score 1):

Pass the options through the forms class `__construct` method, like so:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilder;

class ProductType extends AbstractType
{

    private $options = array();
    public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name')
            ->add('slug')
            ->add('reference')
            ->add('description')
            ->add('active_from')
            ->add('active_till')
            ->add('is_active')
            ->add('category', 'entity', array(
                'class' => 'DEMO\DemoBundle\Entity\Product\ProductCategory',
                'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) {
                    return $er->createQueryBuilder('u')
                        ->where('u.section = :id')
                        ->setParameter('id', $this->options['id'])
                        ->orderBy('u.root', 'ASC')
                        ->addOrderBy('u.lft', 'ASC');
                },
                'empty_value' => 'Choose an option',
                'property' => 'indentedName',
            ));
    }

    public function getDefaultOptions()
    {
        return array(
            'data_class' => 'DEMO\DemoBundle\Entity\Product\Product'
        );
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'demo_demobundle_product_type';
    }

    public function __construct(array $options)
    {
        $this->options = $options;
    }
}
```

And then you can do:

```
new ProductType(array('id'=>1));
```

Comment: I tried this method, and I ended up with an "Undefined variable" error. I copied it exactly, so I cannot figure out why I get that error, as as far as I am concerned, the variable IS being set...

Comment: Haha, yea, already figured that out a few days ago, check out my answer :) Thank for the help!