# create custom options for form builder add method

Tags: symfony, formbuilder

Is it possible to do what i want ?

I know that how to create a form field :

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('field', null, array_of_options)
    ;
}
```

The third parameter of `add method` is an array of predifined options like :`label`, `attr`, etc... and if you do something like this :

```
$builder
    ->add('field', null, array('my_option' => 'my value'));
```

you will get this error :

```
The option "my_option" does not exist. Known options are: "action", "attr", "auto_initialize", "block_name", "by_reference", "cascade_validation", "compound", "constraints", "csrf_field_name", "csrf_message", "csrf_protection", "csrf_provider", "data", "data_class", "disabled", "empty_data", "error_bubbling", "error_mapping", "extra_fields_message", "grouping", "inherit_data", "intention", "invalid_message", "invalid_message_parameters", "label", "label_attr", "mapped", "max_length", "method", "pattern", "post_max_size_message", "precision", "property_path", "read_only", "required", "rounding_mode", "translation_domain", "trim", "validation_groups", "virtual"
```

I have read and understood [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10382075/symfony2-how-to-set-and-get-options-when-using-a-form-class) but it's not what i m looking for. I don't want to pass options in `createForm` method from controller.

What i want is to create a custom `option` for the array of the third parameter in `add method`.

Sorry if i m not clear !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have solved the issue.

First of all, to answer @hcoat's comment, i want to have 3 `custom options` (`open_col`, `close_col`, `col_dims`) for `form theming`. I passed them in the `attr` option:

```
 public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('field1', null, array('attr' => array('open_col' => true, 'col_dims' => '2-8')))
        ->add('field2', null, array('attr' => array('close_col' => true, 'col_dims' => '6-8')))
    ;
}
```

And retrieved those option values like this :

```
{% block form_row %}
{% spaceless %}



{% set open_col, close_col = 'open_col', 'close_col' %}
    {% if open_col in attr|keys %}
    <div class="mws-form-row">
        <div class="mws-form-cols">
            <div class="mws-form-col-{{ (open_col in attr|keys) ? attr['col_dims']:'4-8' }}">
    {% elseif close_col in attr|keys  %}
            <div class="mws-form-col-{{ (open_col in attr|keys) ? attr['col_dims']:'4-8' }}">
    {% else %}
    <div class="mws-form-row">
    {% endif %}

        {{ form_label(form) }}
        <div class="mws-form-item">
            {{ form_widget(form) }}
        </div>
    {% if close_col in attr|keys %}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    {% elseif open_col in attr|keys  %}
    </div>
    {% else %}
    </div>
    {% endif %}
{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock form_row %}
```

It works fine !

Answer (score 2):

I think that your solution isnt perfect. Of course it work but you should consider another solution.

You should use options resolver which allow you to add your own property.
http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/options_resolver.html

So in your formType class you should add following method:

```
public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(
        array(
            'my_option' => 'my_default_value',
        )
    );
}
```

And then you can get this property in twig template as:

```
  {{ my_option }} //it return"my_defaul_value"
  {{ form.your_field_name.my_option }} //it retun your field value
```